# What is the appropriate Stack Exchange site for questions about font editing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have some questions about editing fonts, changing character widths, etc.

What's the most appropriate Stack Exchange site to raise these questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/); they currently have [1,437 questions about fonts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts):

> Questions about matching fonts, using fonts together, **manipulating fonts**, font selection and font purchase and usage rights.

(emphasis mine)

[User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) might be another candidate, especially if you have a conceptual question about how your supposed edit affect user experience.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your purpose.

For just general writing, you might consider writing.SE.

UX.SE might also be a good choice, specifically for user experience (so probably development purposes).

computergraphics.SE exists but I don't think it's necessarily what you're looking for.